# Login Control : WebForms UnobtrusiveValidationMode requires a ScriptResourceMapping for 'jquery'. Add a ScriptResourceMapping named jquery

Tags: asp.net, authentication

I am working on a website in asp.net.
I have a web form without any control. When I add a login control to this form and view this form in Browser, an Error was shown:

> WebForms UnobtrusiveValidationMode requires a ScriptResourceMapping for 'jquery'. Please add a ScriptResourceMapping named jquery(case-sensitive).

I read this solution:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/465613/WebForms-UnobtrusiveValidationMode-requires-a

but I don't find `Global.asax`

Please help me!

Comment: Mind posting some code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can disable this new feature in `web.config` by changing the following key value to `none` like this:

```
<add key="ValidationSettings:UnobtrusiveValidationMode" value="None" />
```

Answer (score 3):

I added below code to `web.config` then my problem was solved.

```
<appSettings>  
    <add key="ValidationSettings:UnobtrusiveValidationMode" value="None" />
</appSettings>
```

Answer (score 1):

Starting .Net 4.5 `Unobtrusive Validation` is enabled by default...

thus one solution will be to set UnobtrusiveValidationMode to none in `web.config` file

```
<configuration>
   ...
   <appSettings>  
      <add key="ValidationSettings:UnobtrusiveValidationMode" value="None" />
   </appSettings>
   ...
</configuration>
```

[Here](http://www.codingfusion.com/Post/WebForms-UnobtrusiveValidationMode-requires-a-Scri) and [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/287278/Unobtrusive-Validation-with-ASP-NET-4-5) you could get  some info on Unobtrusive Validation....