# WebForms UnobtrusiveValidationMode requires a ScriptResourceMapping for 'jquery'

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2012

I am designing a web form for registration purpose with the drag and drop interface. When I add validation control like `RegularExpressionValidator` and required `RequiredFieldValidator` it shows this above titled message when I run it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Login Control : WebForms UnobtrusiveValidationMode requires a ScriptResourceMapping for 'jquery'. Add a ScriptResourceMapping named jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15835846/login-control-webforms-unobtrusivevalidationmode-requires-a-scriptresourcemapp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out i found the solution.
You just need to write this in your C# code

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.UnobtrusiveValidationMode = System.Web.UI.UnobtrusiveValidationMode.None;
}
```

for beginners just double click the components of your page while you are not in debugging mode double clicking a text field will direct you to the C# page.